# PBE solution strategy

Tags: bayesian-game, dynamic-games

I am not comfortable with dynamic games of incomplete info. I am trying to solve the example at https://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/jel.54.2.442 , but can't even come up with a good strategy. How shall I prove the "it can be shown" part of this example?

How do I find the Perfect Bayesian Equilibrium of this game:
Suppose a population of n individuals wishes to consume one unit of a good in each of two periods. Half of the individuals are high-valuation consumers who value the good at 1 in both periods and the
other half are low-valuation consumers who value it at λ ∈ (0, 1/2) in both periods. Each consumer’s valuation is privately known. The good is sold by a monopolist with production cost normalized to 0. The consumers and the firm are risk neutral and (for simplicity) do not discount the future. Also, it is common knowledge that the monopolist possesses a tracking technology (for instance, cookies or
browser fingerprints) with which it can recall whether a consumer purchased the good in the first period and what price he paid for it. Moreover, the monopolist may use this information to make personalized price offers to consumers in the second period.

It can be shown (see, e.g., Taylor 2004; Acquisti and Varian 2005) that on the path
of play in any perfect Bayesian equilibrium of this game the following must hold: The monopolist makes first-period price offers p1 = 1 to all consumers and second period offers p2 = 1 to all consumers regardless of their purchase histories. A low-valuation consumer never purchases the good. A high-valuation consumer purchases with probability 1 in the second period but purchases with probability (1 − 2λ)/(1 − λ) < 1 in the first period (leaving the monopolist just indifferent between p2 = 1 and p2 = λ following a first-period rejection). If the monopolist could publicly commit not to use the tracking technology, then the price offers would be the same, p1 = p2 = 1, but high-valuation consumers would accept with probability 1 in the first period because rejections could never induce lower second-period prices. Thus, the tracking technology leads to strategic first-period rejections by high-valuation consumers, a Pareto inferior outcome that reduces welfare (in the form of monopoly profit) by nλ/(1 − λ)??